# System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' does not contain a definition for 'MaxJsonLength

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'have project in Visual Studio in Framework 4.5.

It is a ASP.NET MVC 4 WebApllication. I'm using JSON to get a lot of data. But when i execute it, it gives me that error: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

So, i want to modify max json length with this code:

```
 protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, System.Text.Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = data,
            ContentType = contentType,
            ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
            JsonRequestBehavior = behavior,
            MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue 
        };
    }
```

But i can't, because I get an error in line **MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue **

Error is: System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' does not contain a definition for 'MaxJsonLength

I have these references in class of controller:

- using System;
- using System.Collections.Generic;
- using System.Linq;
- using System.Web;
- using System.Web.Mvc;
- using WebserviceIPAD.Areas.Api.Models;
- using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

But still getting an error: System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' does not contain a definition for 'MaxJsonLength

Any one knows if I have to import more references?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I checked MSDN, there is a property as MaxJsonLength. When you write the `MaxJsonLength`, do you see it in intellisense?

Comment: I just updated my question, I see MaxJsonLength as it is in image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. I have created new project, every classes and configuration one more time. And know without any problem I can use MaxJsonLength.

Thanks for every one for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

[Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config)

It can be set in the config:

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It doesn't works for me. I have these lines in web.config but error still appears: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

Comment: The max you can set it to is 2147483644.  Is your data larger than that?